# Как организовать и время, например (10:00-12:00) и дни вместе?

Tags: php, mysql

Регистрируется учитель (репетитор), у него есть возможность добавлять учеников (имя, номер, школа, время занятий, в какие дни приходит и т.д.). 
После входа на сайт надо чтобы открывалась его личная страница примерно такого вида:

```
   Сегодня: Четверг
    1 группа (10:00-12:00)
    Алексей
    Евгений 
    Дмитрий
    2 группа (13:00-15:00)
    Сергей
    Маша
    и т.д.
```

Вот проблема в том, что я не понимаю как организовать и время, например(10:00-12:00)  и дни вместе. Сделал так:

```
            $day[0] = "Воскресенье"; 
            $day[1] = "Понедельник"; 
            $day[2] = "Вторник"; 
            $day[3] = "Среда"; 
            $day[4] = "Четверг"; 
            $day[5] = "Пятница"; 
            $day[6] = "Суббота"; 
           $dnum = date("w"); 
           $textday = $day[$dnum];
            echo "Сегодня:  $textday";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM students WHERE day='$textday'",$db);
            $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do {
    printf ("<p><a href='students_view.php?id=%s'>%s</a>",$myrow["id"], $myrow["name"]);
    }
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    ?>
```

Так выводится, например, кто сегодня в пятницу. А как быть со временем?

Еще вопрос по поводу регистрации учителей. Ведь у каждого учителя будет свой список учеников. Нужно для каждого учителя создавать новую таблицу в БД?

И еще один последний вопрос, как можно организовать посещаемость учеников?

Comment: Зачем делаете так?

    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do {
      printf ("<p><a href='students_view.php?id=%s'>%s</a>",$myrow["id"], $myrow["name"]);
    }
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));

Лучше так:

    while ( $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
      printf ("<p><a href='students_view.php?id=%s'>%s</a>",$myrow["id"], $myrow["name"]);
    }

Comment: Та обучается пока) 
@bakusite Если не ошибаюсь, курс Евгения Попова? А то у него в курсе такой почерк прям)

Comment: голос и дикция у него хорошие, но качество материала, я с профессиональной точки зрения говорю - просто ужас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БД заносите время в минутах от начла дня, т.е. если начало промежутка это 10:00, то в бд 10 умножить на 60, и так же с концом промежутка - 12 умножить на 60. Далее узнаём через туже функцию date() время на данный момент. Например, это 10:24, делаем так: $t = 10*60+24. Тогда запрос получится такой:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name FROM students WHERE началопромежутка<=$t and конецпромежутка>=$t,$db);
```

Посещаемость учеников на репетиторство можно организовать только путём того, что репетитор будет вести онлайн журнал у Вас на сервисе.

Comment: Ну а если эти промежутки в разные дни разные? Например в один день в 10:00 а в другой 15:00. Как мне в этот запрос вставлять разные началопромежутка/конецпромежутка автоматически?

Comment: Ну значит в БД должно быть 14 полей, начало_промежутка_в_понедельник, конец_промежутка_во_понедельник и т.д. Главное, способ сравнения я тебе показал. Сам будучи неопытным одну систему записей делал, ну там было куча всяких промежутков) Код здоровый) Сейчас смотрю в код и ничего не понимаю)

Comment: а каким образом организовать посещаемость, если репетитор будет вести онлайн журнал на сервисе?

Comment: Ну репетитор будет записывать в БД был ли тот или иной ученик.
в БД как минимум 3 поля: Ученик, Дата, Статуч
Например Сегодня Володя пришёл, а Женя нет.
И записывается:<br> Володя 13.11.2011 Y<br>
                Женя 13.11.2011 N

Comment: Это ясно, но интересует как сделать это на странице ученика, то есть там где вся инфа об ученике. Нужно создать еще одну таблицу и сделать второй MySQL запрос? так как первый это данные об ученике(имя, школа, номер и т.д.)

Comment: А на странице ученика собирать данные с каждого репетитора, т.е. структура бд такая:<br>
ИД_Репетитора, ИД_Ученика, Дата, Статус<br>
запрос будет: ...WHERE ИД_Ученика='$id'
Ну а далее должно быть всё понятно вроде бы.

Answer (score 1):

> Еще вопрос по поводу регистрации
> учителей. Ведь у каждого учителя будет
> свой список учеников. Нужно для
> каждого учителя создавать новую
> таблицу в БД?

заводите 2(минимум) таблицы учителей и учеников, 
в учительскую заносите id преподавателя и его данные, 
в ученическую id ученика, данные и id его препода,
все - в условие выборки данных учеников добавляете условие фильтрации
по id преподавателя (SELECT * FROM students WHERE teacher_id = 7) 
и видите только его учеников.

Comment: А как при добавлении ученика заносить id его учителя?
В форме добавления сделать поля и в VALUE внести? И делать второй запрос к бд для того чтобы вытащить id препода? у них ведь две разные таблицы.

Comment: Ну, допустим можно к форме добавления ученика добавить элемент select, в котором динамически выводить список учителей из бд. Поле выбора учителя сделать обязательным. Это общая идея. 
Но судя по алгоритму, описанному вами, этот элемент в принципе не обязателен. Добавлять ученика должен учитель, для этого ему, по идее, нужно залогиниться, в процессе логина из БД можно вытаскивать id препода и, допустим, хранить его в сессии и использовать его при добавлении учителем ученика.
Всё

Comment: Спасибо! буду разбираться!